# What's a simple way to list the immediate subdirectories of a given location?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, filesystems, find

Is there a built-in command or a less verbose way of achieving this?

```
find /var/foo -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
```

Or should I just make a tiny shell script or function if I'm doing this sort of thing often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest command seems to be

```
ls -d /var/foo/{*,.[^.]*,..[^.]*}/
```

I believe that will non-recursively list all the subdirectories of `/var/foo`, no matter how stupidly named the directories are or if non-ASCII characters are involved.

```
user@comp:~$ ls -1d /var/foo/{*,.[^.]*,..[^.]*}/
/var/foo/ . . . . . /
/var/foo/-d/
/var/foo/. . . . . ./
/var/foo/. d/
/var/foo/.-d/
/var/foo/..d/
/var/foo/.d/
/var/foo/.字_Ж/
/var/foo/d/
/var/foo/dir1/
/var/foo/dir2/
/var/foo/字/
```

However, `find /var/foo -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d` is easier to both remember and type.

*Below is my original self-answer.*

If one cares not about files beginning with a dot then mibus' answer of

```
ls -d /var/foo/*/
```

would be short and effective.  However if one would like the hidden files to be included then one needs to either stick with

```
find /var/foo -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
```

or try

```
ls -FA /var/foo | grep /
```

The -F places / and the end of directory names (as well as other characters for other types of files).  The -A causes files starting with a dot to be included, except for '.' and '..'.  That is why -a is not used.  The grep won't get any false positives since '/' is not allowed in filenames (at least for POSIX filesystems).

Regarding performance, on my Ubuntu Jaunty installation with just shy of 32k files and directories in /var/foo, find is the fastest, followed by ls -d, and ls -FA with grep comes in last.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -d */
```

"-d" means don't delve into the directories, the "*/" only matches directories.

Comment: What about directories that start with a "." ? I have edited my question since the title asks for subdirectories, and specifying only maxdepth also returns ./ which is not desired

Comment: "ls -d .[A-z0-9]*" will catch most (but not necessarily all).

Comment: Well, you'd need to do ls -d */ .[A-z0-9]*/ to get both regular and a subset of hidden files.